# What military aircraft has six propeller engines?

Tags: aircraft-identification

Today, in south-east Scotland, I saw a plane that looked a bit like a Hercules but had four pods on each wing. I'm pretty sure that three of them were propeller engines and the end one was something else. They all looked a similar size. Height was lowish but not very low and it did not show up on flightradar24.  I could not discern colour. I didn't get much of a look as I rushed in to get binoculars and it was well past and banking to the right when I got out again.

Comment: It would help if you told us where you saw this, what time/date, and any other location details that you remember. The color of the aircraft may help too.

Comment: Six engines, or 6-bladed props?  Some C-130 variants have two pods under each wing; inboard pods are fuel tanks, and external pods are for helo refueling. I can't think of any modern Western plane with six engines these days. Maybe something Russian or Chinese?  Modern Herks ***do*** have 6-bladed props, though.

Comment: The only thing that really comes to mind is a Convair B-36, but those are distinctly pusher props. The aircraft itself is pretty massive compared to a C-130, though.

Comment: Unfortunately I didn't get a photo. At first glance I thought it had 4 engines on each wing, but got the impression that only 3 of each 4 had propellers. It was in SE Scotland and it was heading roughly South a few miles from the coast. Today. I could not discern colour. I didn't get much of a look as I rushed in to get binoculars and it was well past and banking to the right when I got out again.

Comment: Thanks 0xdd, but I've looked up pics of the Convair B-36 and don't think it was that. If C-130s can be fitted with two pods on each wing, then that could be the answer.

Comment: @0xdd I don't think there's even one flying B-36 left, anyway.

Comment: The question title and body ask different things.

Comment: Swept wings? Was it very large, very noisy?

Comment: Juan, the OP has made it clear he meant six engines, not six blades per engine.  You should roll back your edit, because it has changed the meaning of the question.

Comment: "Swept wings? Was it very large, very noisy?"  My impression was it was like a C130 but possibly larger and with longer wings, so no not swept, and same noise as C-130 although that is a very approximate answer.

Comment: Nice thought, Hugh -- but I doubt Bears fly that close to the Scottish coast without a British fighter escort...

Comment: Likely this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lockheed_AC-130#/media/File:AC-130U_gunship_from_the_4th_Special_Operations_Squadron.jpg or one of the other derivatives that have additional pods outside the last set of engines, which includes refueling units. Better image: https://www.militaryfactory.com/aircraft/detail.asp?aircraft_id=1217

Comment: Maury Markowitz  - I dunno - I thought I could see the blur or a propeller x 3 on each wing - and that the three presumed engines all looked the same size and height, but if there are no other options, then that remains the most likely. Thanks. I'll be on the lookout with a camera at hand in case it returns.                                    Thankyou Hugh for correcting the title.

Answer (score 9):

You've probably seen a tanker variant of the C-130, like this KC-130J:

[image: Lockheed KC-130J "Hercules"]
Source: https://www.thedrive.com/the-war-zone

On each wing there is an extra fuel tank and the pod containing the air-refueling hose.

Comment: I probably have - years ago - probably last century, I saw something similar fly over whilst refuelling two helicopters. I am looking back through the mists of time but as far as I can recall there were two helicopters involved and one of them docked as they passed over. It was a sight worth seeing.

Answer (score 2):

It’s most likely a C-130. There’s pictures of four-podded Herculeses online, but so far I haven’t found one with usage rights that allow posting here.